# Two versions of the same project with different design

Tags: git, version-control

Imagine I have a Web app and I want to maintain 2 separate versions of this app with different visual appearance. There are multiple template files across the project in very different locations. These templates will be changed in the new version of design.

The question is what is the best way to implement version control for such case? So I would be able to commit features and business logic (changes to controllers, models, helpers and so on) to both projects at the same time while they will have completely different views.

The obvious solution is to maintain 2 repos and manually add changes to both of them but it does not seem sexy at all.

Comment: If the business logic files will be the same, I don't see why you could need 2 repos. Having two separate (with a common ancestor, to be clear) branches should be enough. Then you can do changes for business logic (that could be on a third branch if you want) and merge it into both branches with _the view_.

Comment: You can't have them in the same folder? I mean,  why don't you work with both in 2 different views folder but in the same web folder

Comment: You could do a submodule with the business logic. Only change it in one place.

Comment: Don't confuse dependency management with source control.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Could you please give more details on it?

Comment: Are the apps fundamentally the same and only visually different? If so, then you could deploy the apps with a different theme being set. If not, then they should be treated separately.

Comment: @eftshift0 I like your approach so far, thank you for suggestion